# Let $G$ be a group, $a$ and $b$ are non-identity elements of $G$, $ab=b^2a$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $a$ and $b$ are non-identity elements of $G$, $ab=b^2a$. If the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$ has order 3, what about the order of the subgroup of $G$ generated by $b$?

Comment: Hint: Compute $a^3ba^{-3}$ in two different ways.

Comment: Or try computing $a^3b$ in one way.

Comment: The problem came up again, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231072/what-can-ab-b2a-and-a-3-imply-about-the-order-of-b-when-b-neq-e/231078#comment513196_231078 --- my answer there expands on Thomas' hint here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$
ab = bba
$$
multiplying gives
$$
aaab = aabba
$$
$$
b = aabba
$$
$$
baa = aabb
$$
Now we van work:
$$
baa  = a(ab)b = a(bba)b = (ab)b(ab) = (bba)b(bba) = b^2(ab)bba = b^2(bba)bba
$$
$$ = b^4(ab)ba =  b^4(bba)ba = b^6(ab)a = b^6(bba)a = b^8aa
$$
so
$$baa = b^8aa \Rightarrow b^7 = e
$$

Comment: So... not pretty, following Thomas Andrews' hint might be easier, but both ways should give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$b=a^2b^2a\Rightarrow b^n=a^2b^{2n}a$$
i.e.,
$$b^{2n}=ab^na^2 $$
then,
$$b^8=ab^4a^2=aab^2a^4=aaaba^6=b$$
whence,
$$b^7=e$$
futhermore, since 7 is a prime and $b$ is not a identity, we can not have a positive interger $k$ less than 7 that 
$$b^k=e$$
hence, 7 is the order of b. (This answer seems easier.)

Comment: Great solution. It does take some insight to try 7.